# What is the Impact of Higher HTTP Connection Pool Manager Sizes on System Resources and Performance?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm currently working on a multithreaded project with Apache HttpComponents Library and using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager class to manage my HttpClient. I've been considering setting a high pool manager size since it improves concurrent connections and enhance performance. However, I'm uncertain about the potential downsides of this approach. Are there any negative effects—such as increased memory usage, higher CPU utilization, or performance issues—that could arise from having a significantly larger HTTP connection pool manager size?

What are the trade-offs and implications of setting a higher pool manager size and whether it might lead to resource constraints or performance degradation under certain conditions?

Default settings: MaxTotal - 20  and DefaultMaxPerRoute - 2
My Setting: MaxTotal - 200 and DefaultMaxPerRoute - 50